# What is the procedure for executing static block?

Tags: java, static

While i executing this program it prints verification only as output.But some of the document says static block will execute first at the time of class loading.I cant understand.Can anybody help me.

```
   public class Threading {

        static void test(){
            System.out.println(" Inside static block ");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("verification ");
        }

    }
```

Output:-verification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a *static method* not a *static block*.
Change your code to :

```
static {
    System.out.println(" Inside static block ");
}
```

And execute.. A static method should be *explicitly* called to executed it. It will not be executed when a class is *initialized*.

PS : *static blocks* are executed when a class is *initialized* not when it is loaded. You could use `Class.forname()` to check that out. A boolean flag `initialize` (passed as an argument to the method) will specify whether to just *load* a class or both *load and initialize* it.

Comment: Ya i got it.If method is static means then we call the method using class name.